# ag-grid MySQL Database import

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, import, ag-grid

I was looking for a grid solution for a while, when I stumbled upon ag-grid. I have managed to import it, works fine, no problem there. Now i want to fill the grid with the data from my online MySQL database. I was wondering is this even possible, and if so, any tips? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)